# Python CSV proplem

Tags: python, csv

For the first time I am having a proble loading a csv into Python.

I am trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616229/create-a-json-tree-from-csv-list-in-python).  My csv file is identical to his, but longer and with different values.

When I run this,

```
import collections
path='../data/struc.csv'
answer = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open(path, 'r+') as istream:
    for line in istream:
        line = line.strip()
        try:
            k, v = line.split(',', 1)
            answer[k.strip()].append(v.strip())
        except ValueError:
            print('Ignoring: malformed line: "{}"'.format(line))

print(answer)
```

Everything runs fine. I get exactly what you would expect.

With out copy and pasting the code from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616229/create-a-json-tree-from-csv-list-in-python), in both instances I get an error.

In the accepted answer, the terminal spits back ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

In the second answer, I get AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'. It also does not work if you adjust it to take a list.

I feel like the problem is the csv file itself. The head of it is

`_id,parent,name,\n
Section,none,America's,\n
Section,none,Europe,\n
Section,none,Asia,\n
Section,none,Africa,\n
Country,America's,United States,\n
Country,America's,Argentina,\n
Country,America's,Bahamas,\n
Country,America's,Bolivia,\n
Country,America's,Brazil,\n
Country,America's,Colombia,\n
Country,America's,Canada,\n
Country,America's,Cayman Islands,\n
Country,America's,Chile,\n
Country,America's,Costa Rica,\n
Country,America's,Dominican Republic,\n`

I have read a lot of stuff about csv's, tried the import csv stuff, and still no luck.
Please someone help. Having this kind of problem is the worst.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

parents=defaultdict(list)
path='../data/struc.csv'

with open(path, 'r+') as istream:
    for i, line in enumerate(istream.split(',')):
        if i != 0 and line.strip():
            id_, parent, name = re.findall(r"[\d\w-]+", line)
            parents[parent].append((id_, name))



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-2b2fd98946b3>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/home/bob/Documents/mega/tree/python/structure.py',       wdir='/home/bob/Documents/mega/tree/python')

  File "/home/bob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

   File "/home/bob/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 78, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/bob/Documents/mega/tree/python/structure.py", line 15, in <module>
    for i, line in enumerate(istream.split(',')):

AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Can you show us exactly the code you are running, and the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: For one thing, you're splitting on `,` but there aren't any in the CSV file.

Comment: @Kenney, thanks for your response.  It is comma separated, it is just that I copied and pasted from liboffice

Comment: @TomDalton Thanks for your response.  I just posted the second from the link, I have tried a number of combinations of getting the file in, this is just the most recent.  All the errors come back on  the same line.

Comment: also, in the code above,` ','` has been tried out of desperation. I used `'\n' `as well.

Comment: This is probably TSV (tab-separated) flavour of CSV. BTW, what is wrong using cvs module for the task?

Comment: @RomanSusi thanks for responding. It is `'/n'`.  I tried import csv but it failed, can you tell me how you would use it?

Comment: @RomanSusi you are right it is TSV version.  I got the /n by adding another row with /n values.  Do you think I should add /n to the name column  string so it has /n in it, or is there a way to load it using TVS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Python has a special module in it's standard library for dealing with CSV of different flavours. Refer to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html).

When CSV file has headers, csv.DictReader is probably more intuitive way to parse the file:

```
import collections
import csv

filepath = '../data/struc.csv'
answer = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open(filepath) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        answer[row["_id"].strip()].append(row["parent"].strip())

print(answer)
```

You can refer to the field in the row by their names in the header. Here I assumed you would like to use _id and parent, but you got the idea.

Also, `dialect=csv.excel_tab` can be added as a parameter to DictReader to parse tab-separated files.

Comment: Thank you I will read all the documentation for csv.  The output is what I needed.  It is people like you that make programming possible for mourns like me.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on doing any analysis on this data, then I would suggest learning the pandas library.  Pandas library takes care of all the details that seem to be tripping you up, making opening a csv file a one-liner.

```
import pandas as pd
csv_file = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

Comment: That is how I usually load it, which makes everything easier.  I am not doing analysis on it though, I am trying to make a json tree